# inline svg in html - how to degrade gracefully?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

See the code below - I am trying to include inline svg in my website. I am following [a neat suggestion](http://shepherdinteractive.com/about-us/blog/2008/12/inline-svg-fallback/) to use the svg switch element so that it degrades gracefully on older browsers. The idea is that browsers which support svg use the first element in the switch block; those which don't ignore all the svg tags and just show the img buried in the second element (i.e. the foreignobject tag) of the switch block.

It works really well ... except that my svg (which is sheet music) necessarily includes text elements and they get rendered (as well as the foreignobject) by older browsers.

Ironically it is easy to deal with this in IE8 and below using conditional comments.

For other older browsers I have a javascript work-around inside the foreignobject which redefines the class of the svg text. It works ... but it feels like a real hack.

Is there a better way to do this (better javascript, a css solution, another way of doing the svg text ...)?

Anyway here is the bare bones of the code:

```
<html>
<head>

<!-- this deals with elements using the svgtext class in old IE browsers -->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
.svgtext { display: none; }
</style>
<![endif]-->
<style type="text/css">
.donotdisplay { display: none; }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<svg ...>
<switch>
<g>
<!-- the svg goes here -->
<text class="svgtext">this gets rendered unless I deal with it</text>
</g>
<foreignObject ...>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
  var inputs=document.getElementsByTagName('text');
  for(i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
    inputs[i].className='donotdisplay';
  }
}
</script>
<!-- the replacement img tag goes here -->
</foreignObject>
</switch>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd look at RaphaelJS, in case that has provision for feature detection - or maybe Modernizr. Not used either, but they'd both be worth a go.

Comment: What other older browsers apart from IE8 that don't support SVG are you trying to support?

Comment: @halfer - Modernizr will add a `svg` or `no-svg` class to the whole document, which can be checked in code or with a CSS selector. It won't automatically fix the problem, but it makes it pretty easy to check.

Comment: @TimMedora - cool, that'd sort it. Must give that a go sometime!

Comment: @RobertLongson - I was looking at the table at http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-html5 which suggests Safari 5.0 won't work (about 3% of traffic on my site). Also older android browsers (about 1% of traffic).

Comment: @TimMedora - thanks, Modernizr sounds like just the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an idea for for browsers other than IE8 and earlier (which need the JS based shiv to recognise the `text` element.) for a CSS-only solution,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Case</title>

<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.createElement("text");
    </script>
<![endif]-->

    <style type="text/css">
      @namespace svg "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
      text { display: none; }
      svg|text { display: inline; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <svg>
      <switch>
        <g>
          <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red"/>
          <text x="20" y="120">this gets rendered unless I deal with it</text>
        </g>
        <foreignObject>
          <p>Use an SVG capable browser</p>
        </foreignObject>
      </switch>
    </svg>

  </body>
</html>
```

The idea here is that browsers that support SVG inline, do so by putting the SVG elements into the "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" namespace, which can then be addressed in the css.

Tested in Firefox 12, IE9, Chrome 18 Opera 11.6, which show the SVG, and Firefox 3.6 and Safari 5.0 which show the fall-back.

JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/rGjKs/

Comment: thanks! Also works on an older android browser which shows the fall-back. The Modernizr library looks interesting but I like this solution a lot as it's much simpler and avoids javascript.

Comment: What does the pipe character `|` mean, in `svg|text`?

Comment: @Sathvik - It's just the separator character between the namespace prefix and the local name of the element. More or less equivalent to the ":" (colon) character in XML.